# What Merkle Tree crate to use inside the runtime?

Tags: runtime

I have seen primitives around Merkle Trees and Merkle Proofs a bit everywhere across the Substrate, Polkadot, and Smoldot repos. I was wondering what the right choice would be for the following use case:

> At the end of each block, read from a storage map in a pallet a series
> of values, and for each of them generate a **fresh** Merkle Root (no
> information on previous roots is stored anywhere) and deposit an event
> with the value identifier and the new Merkle Root. What about
> verifying this proof with access only to the Merkle root, the proof
> itself, and the revealed leaves?

So far, I've found in the `sp_trie::{generate_trie_proof, verify_trie_proof}` the best candidate, but I have seen Merkle stuff also in the beefy pallet, the mmr-pallet does something similar, and Smoldot has also support for Merkle proof generation and verification.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a storage map, you should use a child trie, which automatically tracks the storage root of the data inside of it.

The DevEx around child tries are not really developed yet, but it should be perfectly usable via the raw APIs.

You can see an example in the Crowdloan pallet: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/common/src/crowdloan/mod.rs#L684

Full API docs here: https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/storage/child/index.html

Comment: The pallet is already used in production and the elements under consideration are already part of a quite large storage map. What's an alternative to using child tries?

Comment: I don't know of another option. You can always migrate the data to the child trie using some custom functions or upgrade.